# Can adding basic new SQL Server index create more problems?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm completely new to Indexing and would like to speed up some of my customers systems. My organisation made a mistake and upgraded a few of our customers from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 before testing it fully in-house. The (new) servers are running slower than ever before as result. This is baffling the customers as you can imagine. Each customer has a two SQL Server user databases set up both about 1GB in size and each customer has about 30 users each.

At my organisation, there are not any currently resources to bring in a Developer or DBA to recommend what to do to speed up the new systems in place.

If I were to spend say four weeks learning as much as about SQL Server databases and indexes, do you think it might be a good idea to add some indexes to see if this makes any difference? Also could I easily delete the Indexes to put the system back the way it was so no harm done? Apart from it being a learning experience?

Comment: basic rule of thumb for indexing: any field(s) used in a decision context (`where`, `join`, `order by`, etc...) should have an index on it. that being said, more indexes also means more overhead, and at some point you  may end up with enough overhead wasted on maintaining all of the extra indexes that any gains in query efficiency are lost.

Comment: Yes - indexes often help - ***IF*** you know what queries are causing the performance problems, and which indexes will help. So yes - if you can add the **right** indexes - chances are very good you'll get much better performance - but *finding* and determining those **right** indexes might be a bit of a challenge....

Comment: In the act of reading this now myself, worth a look:  [SQL Server Index Design Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Nice question and good luck!   Also indexes can be easily removed, though you might consider creating a test environment if you're completely new to SQL.

Comment: If you want a really complete look at indexes in sql server from the very basics through some pretty deep dives in sections this is an awesome collection of articles on the topic here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: BTW, after upgrading the database, there are some things you should do to your database. Do some searches but the basics are `DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY`, `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE([DatabaseName])`, `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'` to name a few. This might be your issue.

Comment: Thanks guys - your advice is really useful and this proves that this is the best SQL forum :D

Answer (score 1):

Playing with indexes is often a two-edge sword. Too many is not good and too few is not good either.

However you can start by adding those that most contribute to your queries.

Run this script

```
SELECT
  migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) AS improvement_measure,
  'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' + CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle)
  + '_' + LEFT (PARSENAME(mid.statement, 1), 32) + ']'
  + ' ON ' + mid.statement
  + ' (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'')
    + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END
    + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')
  + ')'
  + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement,
  migs.*, mid.database_id, mid.[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
WHERE migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) > 10
ORDER BY migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
```

(script is from Burt Duncan)

and then analyse the columns like *user_scans, user_seeks, avg_user_impact, last_user_seek, last_user_scan* and etc.
The query returns the index creation statement. You can change the index name to be more user friendly. 
I recommend to use it carefully, not just run all indexes, but one by one and see how the matters are improving.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Check what queries consume the most resources. A quick look at Activity Monitor - Recent Expensive Queries will tell you a lot.
If you dig deeper, you can use the SQL Server Profiler to trace.

Second:
If you know which queries are 'bad', you can do two things: 
Try to improve the query, by using the correct where statements and joins.
or add an index to the tables used by these queries.

Adding an index can cause a huge performance improvement. But it also increases the size of your database file. Adding to many fields to an index, or to many indexes, can slow down the server if you add or edit records in that table.

And of course, internet is your best friend.

Resources:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/298475

http://www.sqlshack.com/dba-guide-sql-server-performance-troubleshooting-part-1-problems-performance-metrics/